# Automatically set a value to a select box after dynamically loaded option value

Tags: jquery, html, tampermonkey

Suppose i have a textbox and a select box with like this.

```
<input type="text" id="txt"><br/><br/>

<select id="sel"></select>
    <option value="0"> Select Value </option>
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2 </option>

</select>
```

when i click on that textbox and write some thing It will generate new option value to the select box by some others method.( Means I am using TamperMonkey for some website and they use some method to populate the option value and i want to automatically select the newly generated option through tamparmoneky ). This is the newly generated option value.

```
<select id="sel"></select>
    <option value="new0"> Select Value </option>
    <option value="new1"> New Option 1</option>
    <option value="new2"> New Option 2 </option>
    <option value="new3"> New Option 3 </option>
</select>
```

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txt').val("somevalue");
  //Trigger onchange event 
  $('#txt').trigger('change');

  // now how to know when option has changed
  $('#sel').change(function() {
     alert( 'Handler for .change() called.');
     $('#sel').val("new3");
  });


});
```

My goal is when The website open the TamperMonkey script automatically enter some value to textbox and trigger a change event. The original site has some function on change event. By which they populate new option value to the select box. Now the problem is i dont understand when they load the option value. How to know when the new option value loaded and then select the value from my Tamper Monkey script?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txt').val("somevalue");
  //Trigger onchange event 
  $('#txt').on('change', function() {
    var txtInp = $('#txt').val();
    $('#sel option').each(function(i) {
      var modVal = txtInp+$(this).val();
      $(this).attr('value',modVal);
    });
  });

  // now how to know when option has changed
  $('#sel').change(function() {
     $(this).find('option:last-child').attr('selected');
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt"><br/><br/>

<select id="sel">
    <option value="0"> Select Value </option>
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2 </option>

</select>
```

Comment: Again I am tellng I don't want to append anything to select box, the websiteatomatically populated option when textbox on change event. Textbox value is not a mandatory option. Just when I change anything it will automatically call a specific funtion to populate the selectbox, and I don't have any control on that script because this is not my site. I just want after automatically enter some text to textbox and trigger change event, and thhis site will populated new option value and I want to set a option among them through my script. I do not need to add option value by me.

Comment: @AshisBiswas you want to select an option through js?

Comment: Yes. But the option which i want to select generated by some other method of this website

Comment: anyway you need to know the function name of script which does that....and at end of line, you can call; $('#sel option:last-child').attr('selected');

Comment: I think this is not the right way. BTW thanks for your help :)

Comment: Without any code or input, how is anyone suppose to give a solution?

Comment: I have added code already. Can you tell me is there any way to know from jquery that if the selectbox option value has changed automatically it trigger an event? Again I am telling i can't alter the code which will generate new option, because this is not my site.

Comment: This might work; you select on change function - $('#sel').change(function() {
         $(this).find('option:last-child').attr('selected');
      });

Comment: change function not triggered.

Comment: Give an alert("check"); replace that line in change function and see if it working...If it is not, then your select box might be ruled out by some jquery plugin which styles it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98323/discussion-between-ashis-biswas-and-yjs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in the textbox `change` event but if it is only `change` event then you can do one thing, as `change` event get fired only after the focus out from textbox and `focusout` event get fired just after the change event so do as below:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txt').val("somevalue");

  //Trigger onchange event 
  $('#txt').trigger('change');

  // attach focusout event to textbox this get called only after the change event
  $('#txt').on('focusout',function(){
    $('#sel').trigger('change'); // trigger select change event or any custom events
  });

  // now how to know when option has changed
  $('#sel').change(function() {
     alert( 'Handler for .change() called.');
     $('#sel').val("new3");
  });

});
```

Hope this will help.(I know this is not good option but it will fit in your case.)

Comment: no need to add focusout. Because Myscript works well. When i trigger change it automatically call the change function which is already created by the website.  I thing there is a function on change event. Because When i trigger change event it automatically generate new option value. Now the problem is i cant select newly generated value by this method. $('#sel').change(function() function not fired when change event done by the textbox.

Comment: @Ashis : "$('#sel').change(function() function not fired when change event done by the textbox"......that's why I attached `focusout` event to textbox, it will trigger `$('#sel').change` and you will able to select newly added item.